# Fastest way to count two-letter pairs in a string

Tags: python, string, performance, numpy, list-comprehension

What is the fastest way to count number of two-letter pairs in a string (i.e AA, AB, AC, ... etc)? Is it possible to use numpy to speed up this computation?

I am using a list comprehension with `str.count()`, but this is quite slow.

```
import itertools

seq = 'MRNLAIIPARSGSKGLKDKNIKLLSGKPLLAYTIEAARESGLFGEIMVSTDSQEYAD'\
      'IAKQWGANVPFLRSNELSNDTASSWDVVKEVIEGYKNLGTEFDTVVLLQPTSPLRTS'\
      'IEGYKIMKEKDANFVVGVCEMDHSPLWANTLPEDLSMENFIRPEVVKMPRQSIPTYY'\
      'RINGALYIVKVDYLMRTSDIYGERSIASVMRKENSIDIDNQMDFTIAEVLISERSKK'

chars = list('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY')
pairs = [''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(chars, chars)]
print(pairs[:10])
print(len(pairs))

['AA', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AK', 'AL']
400

%timeit counts = np.array([seq.count(pair) for pair in pairs])
231 µs ± 5.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

print counts[:10]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since speed is of utmost importance, below is a comparison of different methods:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from collections import Counter

seq = 'MRNLAIIPARSGSKGLKDKNIKLLSGKPLLAYTIEAARESGLFGEIMVSTDSQEYAD'\
      'IAKQWGANVPFLRSNELSNDTASSWDVVKEVIEGYKNLGTEFDTVVLLQPTSPLRTS'\
      'IEGYKIMKEKDANFVVGVCEMDHSPLWANTLPEDLSMENFIRPEVVKMPRQSIPTYY'\
      'RINGALYIVKVDYLMRTSDIYGERSIASVMRKENSIDIDNQMDFTIAEVLISERSKK'

chars = list('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY')
pairs = [''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(chars, chars)]


def countpairs1():
    return np.array([seq.count(pair) for pair in pairs])

%timeit counts = countpairs1()
144 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


def countpairs2():
    counted = Counter(a+b for a,b in zip(seq,seq[1:]))
    return np.array([counted[pair] for pair in pairs])

%timeit counts = countpairs2()
102 µs ± 729 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


def countpairs3():
    return np.array([np.char.count(seq, pair) for pair in pairs])

%timeit counts = countpairs3()
1.65 ms ± 4.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Obviously, the best/fastest method is `Counter`.

Comment: Also, the other method miscount the number of pairs for series of 3 or more repeated letters (i.e. counter will properly return 2x'AA' for 'AAA' whereas the other two methods will return 1x'AA')

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting the counts in a dictionary, the Counter class from collections would process 2-3 times faster:

```
from collections import Counter
chars  = set('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY')
counts = Counter( a+b for a,b in zip(seq,seq[1:]) if a in chars and b in chars)

print(counts)
Counter({'RS': 4, 'VV': 4, 'SI': 4, 'MR': 3, 'SG': 3, 'LL': 3, 'LS': 3, 
         'PL': 3, 'IE': 3, 'DI': 3, 'IA': 3, 'AN': 3, 'VK': 3, 'KE': 3, 
         'EV': 3, 'TS': 3, 'NL': 2, 'LA': 2, 'IP': 2, 'AR': 2, 'SK': 2, 
         ...
```

This approach will properly count sequences of the same character repeated 3 or more times (i.e. "WWW" will count as 2 for "WW" whereas seq.count() or re.findall() would only count 1).

Keep in mind that he Counter dictionary will return zero for counts['LC'] but counts.items() will not contain 'LC' or any other pair not actually in the string.

If needed you could get the counts for all theoretical pairs in a second step:

```
from itertools import product
chars = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'
print([counts[a+b] for a,b in product(chars,chars)][:10])
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you!  `Counter` is slightly faster than `str.count` (196 µs vs. 231 µs).

Answer (score 0):

There is a numpy function, `np.char.count()`. But it appears to be much slower than `str.count()`.

```
%timeit counts = np.array([np.char.count(seq, pair) for pair in pairs]) 

1.79 ms ± 32.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```